# Primary and foreign keys database design

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am creating SQL Server tables for a currency exchange system.

I have one table which is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [CurrencyKeys]
(
    [Key] [nchar](3) NOT NULL, 
    [Currency] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Key] PRIMARY KEY ([Key])
);
```

How would I create the table for the exchange rates itself which references the keys from the `CurrencyKeys` table?

Currently I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [ExchangeRates]
(
    [DateTime] [datetime]NOT NULL,
    [FromCurrCode] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ToCurrCode] [nchar] (3) NOT NULL,
    [Rate] [money] NOT NULL
)
```

Would I need to create (`FromCurrCode`, `ToCurrCode`) as primary key as well?

Comment: Look at this link about foreign key constraints: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to define the foreign keys on the exchangeRates table.

You would define a foreign key for EACH column, like so:

```
alter table [ExchangeRates] add constraint fk_ExchangeRates_01 foreign key (fromCurrCode) references CurrencyKeys([Key]);

alter table [ExchangeRates] add constraint fk_ExchangeRates_02 foreign key (toCurrCode) references CurrencyKeys([Key]);
```

That will define foreign keys for your exchangeRates table.

Comment: But I will also need to add FrommCurrCode, ToCurrCode and DateTime as a Primary Key Correct...?

Comment: What I would do is define an auto-incrementing primary key for the table (i.e. exchangeRates_id) and then create a SEPARATE unique index on those three columsn as in CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_01 ON ExchangeRates(DateTime,FromCurrCode,ToCurrCode);

Answer (score 1):

Don't you just want to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE [ExchangeRates]
(
    [DateTime] [datetime]NOT NULL,
    [FromCurrCode] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ToCurrCode] [nchar] (3) NOT NULL,
    [Rate] [money] NOT NULL,
    Foreign Key([FromCurrCode]) References [CurrencyKeys]([Key]),
    Foreign Key([ToCurrCode]) References [CurrencyKeys]([Key])
)
```

Or are you trying to ask how to maintain primary key values for ExchangeRates table itself. Can you please make yourself clear?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your table could have several rows referring to the same (From,To) pair (to track different exchange rates on different dates)

If that is the case, then the PK could be (FromCurrCode, ToCurrCode, DateTime)

If you are only saving one/the last exchange rate, then (FromCurrCode, ToCurrCode) should be enough.

Comment: Please see comment below Erik's post.

Comment: @user2684009 yes, you should also create FKs referencing CurrencyKeys, one for FromCurrCode, and another one for ToCurrCode.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using natural keys in lieu of surrogate keys.

In order for the ExchangeRates table to use natural keys, you would need to create a composite primary key using FromCurrCode and ToCurrCode

```
CREATE TABLE [ExchangeRates]
(
    [DateTime] [datetime]NOT NULL,
    [FromCurrCode] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ToCurrCode] [nchar] (3) NOT NULL,
    [Rate] [money] NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ExchangeRates] PRIMARY KEY ([FromCurrCode], [ToCurrCode])
)
```

Comment: Would I also not need to ensure that FromCurrCode and ToCurrCode Key References the CurrencyKey Table. Also would I not need to add DateTime as the Primary Key as well as the rates will be pairs on daily basis?

Comment: If the records are snapshots of what the rates were at a given time, you would need to add the DateTime field to the composite key. Also, the ToCurrCode and FromCurrCode would each need foreign keys to the CurrencyKeys table

Comment: Please don't create a 3 column composite clustered index. The space required for all indexes will go up, page splits will occur, gateways to hell will open up... Please do your part to save the world and use an identity surrogate key.